# Isotope animation effects not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have tried using some CSS3 transition on isotope items but its not working properly, elements act in a weird way. What im trying to achieve is for items to have a fading effect, same as this one here http://www.keatonpricedesign.com/#works. Thanks in advance

He is what i have http://codepen.io/GranitS/pen/VYmNdJ

```
<div id="filters" class="button-group">
<button class="button is-checked" data-filter="" id="all-filter">All</button>
<button class="button" data-filter=".one">One</button>
<button class="button" data-filter=".two">Two</button>
<button class="button" data-filter=".three">Three</button>
</div>
<div class="isotope">
<div class="item one"> 1 </div>
<div class="item two"> 2 </div>
<div class="item three"> 3 </div>
<div class="item four"> 4 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item{
width:50px; height:50px;
background-color:red;
float:left;
padding:20px;
margin:20px;
}

.isotope,
.isotope .item {
  /* change duration value to whatever you like */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
     -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
   -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
   -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
      transition-duration: 0.8s;
}

.isotope {
-webkit-transition-property: height, width;
 -moz-transition-property: height, width;
  -ms-transition-property: height, width;
   -o-transition-property: height, width;
      transition-property: height, width;
}

.isotope .item {
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
 -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
  -ms-transition-property:     -ms-transform, opacity;
   -o-transition-property:      -o-transform, opacity;
      transition-property:         transform, opacity;
}
```

Comment: without your isotope custom css there is fading effect, not sure wht you are trying different ?

Comment: @Sarath i want the same effect as this one here http://www.keatonpricedesign.com/#works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be using CSS to try to control the Isotope effects, as these can conflict with Isotope’s transitions, causing the weird effects you see. You should remove your `.isotope` styles and instead use the `visibleStyle`, `hiddenStyle`, and `transitionDuration` options when you initialize Isotope.

```
var iso = new Isotope( '.isotope', {
    itemSelector: '.item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    hiddenStyle: {
      opacity: 0
      /* , transform: 'scale(0.001)' -- disabled scaling */
    },
    visibleStyle: {
      opacity: 1
      /* , transform: 'scale(1)' -- disabled scaling */
    },
    transitionDuration: '0.8s'
});
```

You can read more about these on the [Isotope options page](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/options.html).

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgNaRq) with these changes applied.

**EDIT:**

Isotope doesn’t support turning off only the position transitions with any of the built in options (although you can turn off *all* transitions by setting `transitionDuration` to 0 or using the undocumented `isLayoutInstant: true` option), but you can overwrite the `_positionItem` function to force the behavior you want. Just place the following code at the beginning of your JavaScript:

```
var positionFunc = Isotope.prototype._positionItem;
Isotope.prototype._positionItem = function( item, x, y, isInstant ) {
  // ignore actual isInstant value, pass in `true` to the original function;
  positionFunc(item, x, y, true);
};
```

[Here is an updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Pwbvpj) with this applied.

Comment: Awesome job, but how can i remove this effect of moving boxes to their place, just want them to appear there

Comment: Glad to help! I have added a section on how to remove the position transitions.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not saying this is the best way, but if you do a hard override of the `transition` property, it stops the other animations from happening. You could play with this idea and it might get you on your way:

```
.isotope .item {
  transition-property: opacity !important;
}
```

If you want to play with it, it's your pen with a couple changes: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myOYeE

You can add in @markegli's portion too to help with the fading:

```
hiddenStyle: { opacity: 0 },
visibleStyle: { opacity: 1 }
```

Answer (score -2):

can you not just remove this part of CSS:

```
.isotope,
.isotope .item {
  /* change duration value to whatever you like */
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
 -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.8s;
   -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
      transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```